# Local fluctuations on density in a disolution

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Consider a macroscopic amount of a homogeneous liquid or gas with density $\rho$ assumed to be constant with time.

A very small and fixed region of volume $V$ will have a density $\rho_V$ that depends on time, as the number of particles inside can vary.

How to approach the computation of the fluctuation of $\rho_V$ in time?